# Visual Studio Code - Python autocomplete/autosuggest for subclasses/functions (import foo; want autocomplete for foo.bar.mad.max())

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

the autocompletion/autosuggestion feature works not as I expected. But I think its probably my fault and I miss some configurations.
Normaly, I'm not that bad at googeling, but this time, I did not found a solution for me.

I want to see (and autocomplete) functions inside the vscode ide.
This works basicly and, but only for the top-class.

I will try to explain with an example.

In the end, I want to write `urllib3.util.parse_url()` but lets think i did not now that exact path/name and don't want use external documentation.
In a interactive python shell, I could try tab-completion and could find it.

In (my) vscode, I wrote `import urllib3` and then `urllib3.`, press ctrl+space and look at the suggestions. But the subclassess (like util) are missing. How can show them too?

I found a messy workaround.
`from urllib.` (and ctrl+space) shows me all subclassess and then i can manual try `from urllib3.util import` and now, the util-functions are shown as suggestions. But this is a not a realy good workflow.

Any ideas, what I'm done wrong or missed?